# Select part of id inside id

Tags: jquery

I need to find elements by part of their id, being inside another id.

For example, all elements starting with **bc1_** and **bc2_** inside a form with id **form1000**.

I've tried

```
var o=$('#form1000').eq('id^=bc1_','id^=bc2_');
var o=$('#form1000[id^=bc1_],#form1000[id^=bc2_]');
```

And a few variations on that, but I'm getting no results. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var o=$('#form1000 [id^=bc1_],#form1000 [id^=bc2_]');
```

or

```
var o = $('#form1000').find('[id^=bc1_], [id^=bc2_]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```
var o = $('#form1000').find('[id^=bc1_], [id^=bc2_]');
```

---

Why your previous versions didn't work:

```
var o=$('#form1000').eq('id^=bc1_','id^=bc2_');
```

`eq` reduces *the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.* - so it returns a number, not a jQuery object. Also, you have to use `[...]` for attributes.

```
var o=$('#form1000[id^=bc1_],#form1000[id^=bc2_]');
```

This will select `#form1000` elements with ids that start with `bc_1` or `bc_2`, but an element can have one id.

Comment: Gives me a `unrecognized expression: id^=bc1_,id^=bc2_`

Comment: @Michel You're right. I forgot to use `[...]` because `id` is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/tPUE4/1/

```
$("#form1000 [id^='bc1'], #form1000 [id^='bc2']").css("background","green");
```